# Why don't rvalues have an address?

Tags: c++, expression, rvalue

Why don't rvalues have a memory address? Are they not loaded into the RAM when the program executes or does it refer to the values stored in processor registers?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your question ("Why don't rvalues have a memory address?") is a bit confused.  An rvalue is a kind of expression.  *Expressions* don't have addresses:  *objects* have addresses.  It would be more correct to ask "why can one not apply the address-of operator to an rvalue expression?"

The answer to that is rather simple:  you can only take the address of an object and not all rvalue expressions refer to objects (for example, the expression `42` has a value but does not refer to an object).

Some rvalue expressions do refer to objects, but such objects lack persistence.  An object referred to by an rvalue expression is a *temporary* object and is destroyed at the end of the expression in which it is created.  Such objects do indeed have addresses (you can easily discover this by calling a member function on a temporary object; the `this` pointer must point to the temporary object and thus the temporary object must have an address).

This is the fundamental difference between lvalue expressions and rvalue expressions.  Lvalue expressions refer to objects that have persistence:  the object to which an lvalue expression refers [persists beyond a single expression](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2009/02/03/rvalue-references-c-0x-features-in-vc10-part-2.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Think of `rvalue` as *value* of an *expression*.  The *value* itself doesn't have address. But the *objects* involve in the expression do have address. You can take address of an *object*, even be it a temporary object.

Consider this,

```
const int & i = 10; //ok
```

Here, `10` is an rvalue, so it *appears* that `&i` is an address of the `10`. No, that is wrong. `&i` is an address of *the temporary object* of type `int`, which is created out of the expression `10`. And since the temporary object cannot be bound to non-const reference, I use `const`. That means, the following is an error:

```
int & i = 10; //error
```

Answer (score 1):

The question mixes two different aspects related to the "specification" and to the "implementation".

The "specification" define some abstract rules that defines how the language behave respect to an abstract machine it works with.
Adapt that "abstract machine" to the "real one" under it its a purpose of the compiler (not the language).

What the specification is enforcing is that -by the language stand point- a "storage" (a piece of memory with a proper address) is given only to objects that have a *name* (for the existence of the scope that name lives) or that are dynamically allocated with an explicit request (`new`).
Everything else is "temporary": assign, copy and moves like an object, but is not *required to exist* in a well defined and stable place. At least, not for the purpose of the language.

Of course, that has to stay (physically) somewhere, so you can -with appropriate casting or conversion- trying to guess a memory address. But the language specification does not grant any consistent behavior if you try to actively use it.
That means that different compilers can behave differently, and optimize the better they can respect to the real machine they target.

Answer (score -1):

What do you mean, rvalues do have an address. Ever tried

```
Type const value& = rvalue;
Type const* address = &value;
```

Comment: You can capture a const reference to an rvalue, and then get the const pointer to it, just like in my code example.

Comment: @K-ballo: No. the cons reference is bound to the *temporary* **object**.

Comment: The value category is a property of an expression. In your example we assume that `rvalue` is indeed an rvalue but `value` is really an lvalue. The way some variable (`value` in this case) was initialized does not affect its value category when it is used in an expression later on. The fact that the variable`value` was initialized by an rvalue doesn't mean anything for the value category of `value` when used in the expression `&value`. It is still an lvalue.

Comment: @Nawaz or an xvalue.

Answer (score -2):

Simply take this case

```
int a = 1 + 2;
```

1+2 gets resolved to 3.

Ask yourself:

- Is 3 an object?
- Where would 3 be located in memory?

When you need the address of an object, you use &.

If rvalues would be addressable, it means you could declare a pointer to where your computer decided to store 3

```
int* a = &3;
```

Does that seem right? :)