# Wrapper Function for a Recursive Function that takes a "pass by reference" value

Tags: c++

Here's the question: I'm trying to do,

```
Node* foo(Node *& ptr, other args) {
  // some work here
}
```

In the wrapper function, I have to declare a temporary value (which is meaningless):

```
Node* wrapper( ... ) {
  Node* p = nullptr;
  return foo(p, other args);
}
```

Is there any way to get rid of the first line in the wrapper function? Thanks!!

Comment: Can you change the signature of `foo`? It seems `Node *& ptr` is not necessary at all. (Also, the question could have better answers if you provide more information, like what `wrapper` is doing)

Comment: Why do you have to declare a temporary value ? Also, can't you just pass p as an argument to the wrapper function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess in `foo` you assign `ptr` some value (otherwise the `*&` has no value). You cannot pass `nullptr` and you have to declare a pointer like you shown in the `wrapper` because `nullptr` is an rvalue. An rvalue is an expression, or an "unnamed object" and you cannot take the address of it. There is more information here [Why don't rvalues have an address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370109/why-dont-rvalues-have-an-address).