# Using NSInvocation setArgument: with value returned from NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have the following issue.

I have an NSArray of values that I need to loop across and set the contents as the respective arguments for an NSInvocation object. Consider the following code:

```
NSArray *args = @[@"test"];
```

later I would like to do something like:

```
for ( i = 0; i < [args count]; i++)
{
    [invocationObj setArgument: [args objectAtIndex: i] atIndex: i+2];
}
```

but this doesn't work. It gives the following warning:

```
Implicit conversion of Objective-C pointer type 'id' to C pointer type 'void *' requires a bridged cast
```

The invocation object is dynamic (for both target/selector and args) and so I don't know the contents of the args array when i am setting the arguments of the respective invocationObj. Is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: You set the arguments **right before** calling the invocation.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Gives a compiler error? Signal? Exception? On assign or invoke? Sends the wrong arguments? Doesn't send a message?

Comment: Check that `invocationObj` is not `nil` at that point.

Comment: Are you getting any exception??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass a pointer location into `setArgument:atIndex:`. Specifically, this part from the docs

> When the argument value is an object, pass a pointer to the variable (or memory) from which the object should be copied:

So try this...

```
id argument = [args objectAtIndex: i];
[invocationObj setArgument:&argument atIndex: i+2];
```

Comment: Yes, sorry. I didn't mean they are the same. Just that the setArguments accepts void * of which id is a subset of. Removed that to be clear.

Comment: This works perfectly thanks! One question though. Why can't I do: [invocationObj setArgument: &[args objectAtIndex: i] atIndex: i+2]; ??

Comment: Because the compiler won't allow an address-of operation on an r-value expression. More explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7370156/98048

Comment: If you have a variable number of elements in the array and need a more generic solution to set multiple arguments, this will unfortunately not work.

Comment: @ricosrealm Yes it will. The answer is meant to be placed within a loop body

Comment: @JasonHarwig how would you do this for a variable number of arguments and generate a variable number of locally scoped variables in a loop?